# Configuring SLURM so it requires the user to specify --account

Tags: config, default, account, slurm

I'm trying to figure out how to configure SLURM so that a user is required to specify --account when using the SLURM commands (salloc, sbatch, srun). Effectively I want to disable the default account behavior.

Has anyone out there found a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to set the `AccountingStorageEnforce` parameter to `associations` in `slurm.conf`.

> AccountingStorageEnforce
>       This controls what level of association-based enforcement to impose on job submissions. Valid options are any combination of
>   associations, limits, nojobs, nosteps, qos, safe, and wckeys, or all
>   for all things (expect nojobs and nosteps, they must be requested as
>   well).
>
> By enforcing Associations no new job is allowed to run unless a corresponding association exists in the system. If limits are enforced
>   users can be limited by association to whatever job size or run time
>   limits are defined.

Then, with the `sacctmgr` command, make sure the default account has no access to the defined partitions. Effectively, the users will be denied submission if they do not specify a valid account.

Another option is to write a custom [submission plugin](http://slurm.schedmd.com/job_submit_plugins.html), which you can write in Lua. In that script, you can check whether the `--account` parameter was set and deny submission with a custom message if it was not.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same requirement to force users to specify accounts and, after finding several ways to fulfill it with slurm, I decided to revive this post with the shortest/easiest solution.

The slurm lua submit plugin sees the job description before the default account is applied. Hence, you can install the slurm-lua package, add "JobSubmitPlugins=lua" to the slurm.conf, restart the slurmctld, and directly test against whether the account was defined via the job_submit.lua script (create the script wherever you keep your slurm.conf; typically in /etc/slurm/):

```
-- /etc/slurm/job_submit.lua to reject jobs with no account specified

function slurm_job_submit(job_desc, part_list, submit_uid)
    if job_desc.account == nil then
            slurm.log_error("User %s did not specify an account.", job_desc.user_id)
            slurm.log_user("You must specify an account!")
            return slurm.ERROR
    end
    return slurm.SUCCESS
end

function slurm_job_modify(job_desc, job_rec, part_list, modify_uid)
    return slurm.SUCCESS
end

return slurm.SUCCESS
```

Errors resulting from not specifying an account appear as follows:

```
# srun --pty bash
srun: error: You must specify an account!
srun: error: Unable to allocate resources: Unspecified error

# sbatch submit.slurm
sbatch: error: You must specify an account!
sbatch: error: Batch job submission failed: Unspecified error
```

These errors are also printed out to the slurmctld log so that you know what the resource allocation issue was for the particular job:

```
[2017-09-12T08:32:00.697] error: job_submit.lua: User 0 did not specify an account.
[2017-09-12T08:32:00.697] _slurm_rpc_submit_batch_job: Unspecified error
```

As an addendum, the [Slurm Submit Plugins Guide](https://slurm.schedmd.com/job_submit_plugins.html) is only moderately useful and you will probably be much better off simply examining the [Lua job_submit plugin implementation](https://github.com/SchedMD/slurm/blob/master/src/plugins/job_submit/lua/job_submit_lua.c) for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding upon damienfrancois's answer, here is what I did :

1. In `slurm.conf` : `AccountingStorageEnforce=associations,qos,limits`
2. Restart `slurmctld` on slurm controller node and `slurmd` on the compute nodes
3. Create an account to put your users in

```
sacctmgr list associations                          # Check first
sacctmgr add account pie Cluster=slurm Parent=root
```

4. Add user(s) to account `pie`

```
sacctmgr add user bill account=pie Cluster=slurm
```

5. Create null/none account, set max jobs to 0

```
sacctmgr add account none cluster=slurm parent=root
sacctmgr modify account none set maxjobs=0
```

6. Make default account for user `bill` the `none` account.

```
sacctmgr add user bill account=none DefaultAccount=none
```

Since he cannot submit jobs under `none` because `maxjobs=0`, he has to specify `--account=pie` when he submits jobs.